# TestNG i want to show the @BeforeClass and @AfterClass method in Report

Tags: testng

How to tell the testng to show all methods in report irrespective of annoations.I want to capture both @Test and configuration method to e displayed in logs.

My Requirement:

In my project we attach log for each method whether the method is pass or fail.
I am able to attach logs for each test method and it shows the method in report.But when i use @Afterclass to do some action after all the method is executed i am not able to attach the logs as this @Afterclass is not shown in reports .@Afterclass method is shown in reports only when their is failure .

My question is can we display the @AfterClass method in report at all times even when there is no failure.

Comment: Please add more details and be clear into what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

`@After*` and `@Before*` are not considered as test methods and reporters may not display them.

But you can use your own reporter with its own logic. See the documentation: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-reporters